# Calculus 3 (for engineers) VS. Ordinary Differential Equations and Numerical Methods

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

- I am new to this exchange but am seeking some advice regarding my upcoming course selection.

***Question:***

I am studying Computer Science in University and am very interested in AI / Machine Learning, and **I want to know which course YOU think has more relevance / usefulness in my future goal of joining the AI/ML field.** These areas are quite broad so if needed my main interest is in Machine Learning and Computer Vision.

I have an option to choose between two classes this upcoming semester between the courses listed above. As I am still relatively "new" to the ML atmosphere, I am seeking guidance from someone who knows a little more.

*Frankly, most of these topics in the course descriptions are slightly intimidating and mean nothing to me right now.*

***Course descriptions:***

**Calc 3:** 
Extrema of functions of several variables. Multiple integration and applications. Vector fields and their derivatives. Curves. Vector differential operators. Line integrals. Surfaces and surface integrals. Theorems of Stokes, Gauss, etc.

**ODE and Numerical Methods:** 
General concepts. First order equations. Linear differential equations of higher order. Differential operators. Laplace transforms. Systems of differential equations. Series solutions about ordinary points. Numerical methods including error analysis; numerical differentiation, integration and solutions of differential equations.

***Side Note (Optional):***

In general I would like to stay a little more on the "practical/applied" areas where I can actually develop. I know a lot of "heavy" math and research is involved in these fields, and although this is very cool, this is not where my interest lies. Basically, I would like to have a decent background in math where I am not scared of the equations I see, but don't necessarily need the aptitude to prove the things I use. Any other general courses, topics to study, or tips are greatly appreciated; I'm really trying to make my way and break through into this overwhelming field!

Thanks!

Comment: TBH, i would take both courses if somehow possible.

Comment: This types of question should be aimed at the institution staff, as described in [Math.SE help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Riquelme Ah, so they are both quite important? I kind of figured that. I'll see how if I can re-arrange my schedule a bit.

Comment: I don't think odes are used much in machine learning. On the other hand, calculus is the foundation of optimization, which definitely is. IMO, if you can only take one it should definitely be calculus.